# How to get Chef api credentials?

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to use following script:
https://github.com/evanlok/chef-node-cleaner

Here the following variables are required:

`CHEF_API_ENDPOINT
CHEF_API_CLIENT
CHEF_API_KEY`

I could not find what would be the value of these variables.
CHEF_API_ENDPOINT may be the chef server url and CHEF_API_KEY is validator key. Not sure about these. 
Please suggest what would be the value of these variables or how to get the value of these variables.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You would get them from the configuration of your CHEF server.

Please see the chef server api setup at https://docs.chef.io/api_chef_server.html

Comment: which file on chef server?

Comment: I am not getting it. Can you pls tell me directly what would be the value of those variables?

Comment: They aren't files anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new client with `knife client create`. You'll probably have to customize the ACLs to make sure it has the right permissions though. If you're unfamiliar with Chef client and ACL management, I probably wouldn't use this script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain why not to use this script and what would be the best way to remove dead nodes from chef server

Comment: Because it was written before Chef Server 12 was released, and so doesn't appear to have any instructions on what ACLs are needed for it to work. I'm sure it still works fine, but if you are starting as a new user it might be hard to get it working.